# Expand javascript div in sharepoint designer

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I have done some searching on SO and Google, but we are short on time.  We have been tasked with creating some content that will be plugged into a content editor web part.  Part of what they want has collapsible sections that start out collapsed.  This is all done with JavaScript.  However, the client wishes to be able to go into SharePoint Designer (SPD) and edit the links under the collapsed section.  When viewed in SPD, the region is collapsed.  Is there a way to open the area up using the WYSIWYG editor in SPD so that they can edit the area? Even if it somehow looking at the user agent and acting on that.

Note that we do not have SharePoint or SharePoint Designer to fiddle with.

Any help is would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving a user to edit links via SharePoint designer seems bad approach. Other way may be is you create a Custom/link list render it using xslt/js. Than anytime user wants to edit links or remove one just update the list.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I really appreciate it.  I am going to forward your suggestion, but there are two problems.  The first is that we have no real control over how they are going to do things once we hand this over.  The second is that the people we are dealing with are not technical - at all - and they want WYSIWYG.  If it were up to me, I would only give access to Designer to the IT folks.  In my opinion anyone who cannot edit HTML should not have access to the Designer.  All kinds of BAD THINGS can accidentally be done with it.